# List calculation with elements not equal to zero

Tags: python, list, calculation

Let's assume I have a list:

```
list1 = [16620, 22032, 0, 0, 0, 136813, 137899, 0, 199546, 204804]
```

I am looking for a new list that subtracts every 'non-zero' value from the following 'non-zero' value, e.g. 22032-16620, 137899-136813. 'Zero' values will stay untouched.
In addition to that, the subtracted 'non-zero' value should change to zero.
The output would look something like:

```
list2 = [0, 5412, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1086, 0, 0, 5258]
```

Please note that the numbers, the length of the list and its distribution of elements may vary, e.g. a list could also look like

```
list1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 95472, 0, 0, 104538, 0, 0, 0, 0, 187649, 0, 0, 204841, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

which should turn into:

```
list2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9066, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17192, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

As you can see, the number of elements stays the same for list1 and list2. Also, there is always an even number of 'zero' values and an even number of 'non-zero' values.
Help is greatly appreciated!

What I have so far:

```
from itertools import cycle, chain
list1 = [11545, 15334, 71341, 73861, 0, 0, 170374, 171671]
newlist = [list1[i + 1] - list1[i] for i in range(len(list1)-1)]
list2 = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(newlist[0::2], cycle([int()]))))
print list2
```

The output print list2 looks like I imagine it to be, yet it won't work for a list that looks like:

```
list1 = [16620, 22032, 0, 0, 0, 136813, 137899, 0, 199546, 204804]
```

Comment: Help with what?  You haven't posted any code to help you with.

Comment: Please detail the logic behind how `list1` is converted into `list2`.

Comment: I have added the code I've got so far but only works for a certain order of lists.

Comment: Your explanation and the desired output do not agree.  You say you want "a new list that subtracts every 2nd value not equal to zero from the previous value", but in the sample `list1 = [16620, 22032, ...`, the second value not equal to zero is `22032`, and if you subtract that from the previous value `16620` you should get `-5412`, but your desired output instead has `5412` (not negative).  Please clarify.

Comment: @HeapOverflow We can't know which one is correct -- the explanation or the sample output, so I think we need clarification from OP.

Comment: @JohnGordon Unless the text looks like it's written by someone else, I have more faith in the example data :-). The added code also agrees with the data. But yeah, they should fix in any case.

Comment: You guys are absolutely right. I've been trying for so long, I ended up mixing up the examples. The code in the example above should be right by now.

Comment: @HeapOverflow: There is always an even number of 'zeros' and an even number of 'non-zeros', however, there position within the list may vary. This is exactly why my posted code is working for some lists but not for others.

Comment: I think this was a language issue (English is not my native language) :-)
It's been fixed for sure by now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy over, but adjust non-zero values, keeping track of the previous one.

```
list2 = []
prev = None
for curr in list1:
    if curr:
        if prev:
            curr -= prev
            prev = None
        else:
            prev = curr
            curr = 0
    list2.append(curr)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so, so much! I would have never guessed this code, even though it kind of looks so simple :-)